# why .popup('open') is not working in jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am opening a pop up screen on anchor tag I don't know why it is not open. I used many time this line to open the pop up. It always open. But this time it is not when I inspect it show 'display none' with no content.

I follow the steps

1. Press add button (generate row)
2. Click icon on the row (right side). Show pop up screen with edit and delete option.
3. Press edit. It should show pop up screen, but it is not showing...

http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/11/

```
$('.edit_h').click(function(){

    alert("edit ID:"+$(this).data('originalId'));
    $("#editTestCaseId").popup("open");

})
```

Comment: If you're talking about the "Edit/Delete/Copy" popup, it worked for me in Chrome on both my computer and my phone.

Comment: no.after click of "edit" button of that pop up it show another pop up

Comment: please follow the above steps given

Comment: any idea ? of this question..?

Comment: I'm not sure. I followed your steps like you said and sure enough, it doesn't work. However, I am not familiar with .popup() I tried to find documentation on it but gave up. If you link me to it, I'd be willing to give it a second look.

Comment: Please check the documentaton http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/pages/popup/

Comment: Thanks, looking into it.

Comment: What browser are you in, I see the popup that displays "edit ID:tc_1" after I click edit. I'm using chrome.

Comment: @caspian i am using chrome same ..no that is alert ..after that there is line     $("#editTestCaseId").popup("open");
 this is not excecuting

Comment: any update of this Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a solution, but it is certainly a workaround.

After tracing the CSS and finding that jQuery was probably just being too greedy with its class adding/removing logic, I decided to try the `popup("open", ...)` call manually using the console. As it turns out, it works fine when done that way. I tried putting the call in the code in different places and in multiples to no avail. As it turns out, other people have run into the same problem. The workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23429545/482489) seems to do the trick:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#editTestCaseId").popup("open");
}, 100);
```

Why this has to be done? I have no idea.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/12/

Comment: thanks for help..may be it is correct way ...I will mark after few min may be other give better solution